# Why Does Fixing Position of an div destroys it's outlook in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
<div class="topnav">
<div class="container">
    <span class="icons">
        <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"> </i> Contact</a>
    </span>
    <span class="icons">
        <a href="#showcase"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"> </i> Showcase</a>
    </span>
    <span class="icons">
        <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> Home</a>
    </span>         
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
}

.topnav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[As you see here, if the position is relative it will take the full width of the container but when I make it fixed, the right part cuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvu81.jpg)

Comment: Add width: 100%; on your .topnav CSS.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

Comment: In the code you have provided, the `topnav` div is not closed.

Comment: Added width 100% and worked, special thanks to @NerdyGeek

Comment: You’re welcome, @Moe!

Answer (score 1):

position: fixed 
means The element is positioned relative to the browser window, not with respect to its parent div. Pls use this for reference

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

ps why not try absolute or sticky for things like nav-bar